# Why is the line callback no more triggered after zoom?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

In MATLAB (R11) following code sets a callback to a line plot and is working well, before I zoom or pan the axis. After that it is not triggered anymore. What is happening? How to correct that?

```
function line_callback 
figure() 
hl  = line(randn(1,2),randn(1,2),'ButtonDownFcn',@set_lines); % plot and set callback 

function set_lines(cb,eventdata) 
lw = get(cb,'LineWidth');% get current line width 
set(cb,'LineWidth',lw+1) % increase current line width
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of MATLAB?

Comment: Why indeed? Because I do not choose at work:-(

Comment: Oh boy lol.  I'll get to your question in a minute, but how the heck are you running it?  R11 is Windows only and didn't use the JVM.  You must be using an older version of Windows... 95? 98? XP?

Comment: Sure... This is the old package ! WinXP (again, not my choice!)

Comment: @down-voter: are you down voting because I'm stupid or because the question is? I feel that the answer may help someone as stupid as me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: the line callback was not fired because I put the Edit Plot mode on (clicked on the arrow tool in the figure). Line callback do not seem fired when any of the figure tool is activated. 
When I deactivate Edit Plot mode, all works. My mistake!